# Show textbox values depending upon combobox selection

Tags: c#, sql, string, combobox, textbox

In SQL I have column `price(nchar(10)), product_category(nvarchar(50))`
I want to show the price from sql to certain textbox after selecting item from combobox. Getting Continuous error and when I  try `GETOrdinal("ColumnName")` then it shows only 0 in textbox when I select from combobox
kindly take me out of this. thanks in advance

```
private void cb_ocat_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Pizza Mania;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand("select Distinct(Price) from product where Product_category='" + cb_ocat.Text + "'", sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            SqlDataReader sqlrdr = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader();


            while (sqlrdr.Read())
            {
                String price = sqlrdr.GetInt32("Price").ToString();//getting error here that dbdatareader(int) has some invalid arguments
                txt_oprice.Text = price;
            }
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first line of this question you have price(nchar(10)  is price nchar or an Int in your SQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead..

```
while (sqlrdr.Read())
                {
                    String price = sqlrdr["Price"].ToString();//getting error here that dbdatareader(int) has some invalid arguments
                    txt_oprice.Text = price;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks Man You are a life Savor